# How do I find which app on my phone is putting photos deleted by Google photos in a Recycling Bin? (I can't find the bin. Phone full.)

Tags: data-recovery, delete

I connected my phone to my laptop and searched the phone for "recycl" - no matches found.
I searched my phone apps for "bin" - no relevant matches found.
I have 200 apps on my phone, but didn't find any that seem like they would create a recycling bin.
How can I find the recycle bin / recycling bin?
In Google Photos, I deleted 500 MB of photos that had uploaded.  I increased available space by zero.

---

Samsung A8, 2018.  Android 9.

Comment: The Google Photos app has a "Trash" area.  If you are updated to the latest version, you will find the Trash screen in the Library tab.  From there, you can truly delete the photos and reclaim device space.

Comment: Thanks @CzarMatt!